# redux-persist doesn't keep the state on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I've combined `redux-persist` with Redux to keep the state between app restarts. Currently, on the dev build, it never keeps the state.

My store

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist:['users', 'activity', 'meeting', 'workshop', 'predavanja', 'klizni', 'meetings', 'standing']
}

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  darkMode: persistReducer(persistConfig, darkReducer),
  users: userReducer,
  activity: activity,
  meeting: meeting,
  workshop: workshop,
  predavanja: predavanja,
  klizni: klizni,
  meetings: meetings,
  standing: standing,
});
```

I keep logging the state of the state I want to persist but it keeps returning to the default state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason, you decided to blacklist each reducer in the config? If you are trying to persist all your Redux state, you should not define any blacklist. Furthermore, I can't see, how you are creating your redux store, but it should look something like

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
...
const store = createStore(persistReducer(persistConfig, allReducers));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

In your root component, you should inject the store like the following:

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
...
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
         .....
      </PersistGate>
   </Provider>
);
```

The reducers should look like in the following code snippet:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage
}

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  darkMode: darkReducer,
  users: userReducer,
  activity: activity,
  meeting: meeting,
  workshop: workshop,
  predavanja: predavanja,
  klizni: klizni,
  meetings: meetings,
  standing: standing,
});
```

If you follow all these steps, your whole redux store should be persisted.

Comment: I've blacklisted the ones I don't want to persist for now since they'll likely change each time the app is restarted